# how to group data and using optional attribute in lodash?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am using lodash for data manipulation but I am stuck when I need to group data and aggregate data with optional attribute.

I have below data through which i want below output:

```
var data = [{product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2015', score:'43.3'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2015', score:'22'},
    {product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2015', score:'33.1'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2015', score:'28'},
    {product: 'Cheese Cocoa', year: '2015', score:'86.4'},{product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2015', score:'72.4'},
    {product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2016', score:'40'},{product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2016', score:'45.8'},
    {product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2017', score:'33.3'},{product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2017', score:'43.3'},
    {product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2017', score:'16.73'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2016', score:'73.4'},
    {product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2017', score:'50'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2017', score:'.1'},
    {product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2016', score:'50.4'},{product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2016', score:'3.6'},
    {product: 'Cheese Cocoa', year: '2016', score:'65.2'},{product: 'Cheese Cocoa', year: '2017', score:'82.5'},
    {product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2017', score:'39.1'}];
```

And the expected output:

```
[{product: 'Matcha Latte', '2015': 43.3, '2016': 85.8, '2017': 93.7},
        {product: 'Milk Tea', '2015': 83.1, '2016': 73.4, '2017': 55.1},
        {product: 'Cheese Cocoa', '2015': 86.4, '2016': 65.2, '2017': 82.5},
        {product: 'Walnut Brownie', '2015': 72.4, '2016': 53.9, '2017': 39.1}]
```

I tried following but how to proceed further:

```
 var ans = _(data)
.groupBy('product')
.value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure javascript you can reduce it:

```js
var data = [{product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2015', score:'43.3'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2015', score:'22'}, {product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2015', score:'33.1', mat:50},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2015', score:'28', mat:50}, {product: 'Cheese Cocoa', year: '2015', score:'86.4'},{product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2015', score:'72.4'}, {product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2016', score:'40'},{product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2016', score:'45.8'}, {product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2017', score:'33.3'},{product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2017', score:'43.3'}, {product: 'Matcha Latte', year: '2017', score:'16.73'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2016', score:'73.4'}, {product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2017', score:'50'},{product: 'Milk Tea', year: '2017', score:'.1'}, {product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2016', score:'50.4'},{product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2016', score:'3.6'}, {product: 'Cheese Cocoa', year: '2016', score:'65.2'},{product: 'Cheese Cocoa', year: '2017', score:'82.5'}, {product: 'Walnut Brownie', year: '2017', score:'39.1'}];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {product, year, score, mat})=>{
   acc[product] =  acc[product] || {product};
   acc[product][year] = (acc[product][year] || 0) + Number(score);
   if(mat) acc[product][`${year}_mat`] = (acc[product][`${year}_mat`] || 0) + mat;
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @gorak for your reply. i have one more question here if my data conatins [{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2015","score":"43.3", "mat": 40},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2015","score":"22", "mat": 30}] and i want [{product: 'Matcha Latte', '2015_score': 75.3, '2015_mat': 70}]

Comment: @Mayur, You can do that with similar logic , I have implemented with `score`

Comment: @Mayur I have updated my answer, according to your data. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

Format the data to objects that have a key of the year, with the value. Group by the `product`, and then map and merge each group. While merging if the first value (`a`) is a number, combine it with the 2nd value (`b`). If not return `undefined`, so that standard merge algorithm used by `_.mergeWith()` would be used.

```js
const data = [{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2015","score":"43.3"},{"product":"Milk Tea","year":"2015","score":"22"},{"product":"Milk Tea","year":"2015","score":"33.1"},{"product":"Milk Tea","year":"2015","score":"28"},{"product":"Cheese Cocoa","year":"2015","score":"86.4"},{"product":"Walnut Brownie","year":"2015","score":"72.4"},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2016","score":"40"},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2016","score":"45.8"},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2017","score":"33.3"},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2017","score":"43.3"},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2017","score":"16.73"},{"product":"Milk Tea","year":"2016","score":"73.4"},{"product":"Milk Tea","year":"2017","score":"50"},{"product":"Milk Tea","year":"2017","score":".1"},{"product":"Walnut Brownie","year":"2016","score":"50.4"},{"product":"Walnut Brownie","year":"2016","score":"3.6"},{"product":"Cheese Cocoa","year":"2016","score":"65.2"},{"product":"Cheese Cocoa","year":"2017","score":"82.5"},{"product":"Walnut Brownie","year":"2017","score":"39.1"}];
    
const result = _(data)
  .map(({ year, score, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, [year]: +score })) // create objects with the year as the key, and score as the value
  .groupBy('product')
  .map(g => _.mergeWith({}, ...g, (a, b) => _.isNumber(a) ? a + b : undefined)) // merge and sum up the score of each year, if it appears more than once
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ori Drori for your reply. i have one more question here if my data conatins [{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2015","score":"43.3", "mat": 40},{"product":"Matcha Latte","year":"2015","score":"22", "mat": 30}] and i want [{product: 'Matcha Latte', '2015_score': 75.3, '2015_mat': 70}]

Comment: In this phase, you can generate any key you want instead of `[year]`. Something like this should work: `.map(({ year, score, mat, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, [`${year}_${_.isUndefined(mat) ? 'score' : 'mat'}`]: +score }))`. You might want to extract the string key generation to a function to make it more readable.